# Ruby on Rails: Encountered a syntax error while rendering template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

llevo un par de días con Ruby on Rails, y estoy haciendo el getting started de su página de guías.
El problema llega cuando después de hacer el create y el read, quiero hacer acceder a la vista de creación de nuevos artículos y me salta un error de template.
El código lo tengo igual al de la guía, lo he revisado unas cuantas veces y no sé encontrar el error. Agradecería mucho si alguien me pudiese ayudar:

El código el qual me dice que tengo errores:

```
<h1>New Article</h1>

<%= form_with scope: :article, url: articles_path, local: true do |form| %>

<%= if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2>
            <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %>
            prohibited this article from being saved:
        </h2>
        <ul>
            <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>

    <P>
        <%= form.label :title %><br>
        <%= form.text_field :title %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= form.label :text %><br>
        <%= form.text_area :text %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= form.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

y éstos son los errores que según Rails tengo:

```
app/views/articles/new.html.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting then or ';' or '\n'
 app/views/articles/new.html.erb:17: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting ')'
app/views/articles/new.html.erb:32: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting ')'
app/views/articles/new.html.erb:36: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting ')'
```

pero he revisado mi código comparándolo con el de la guía y está exactamente igual.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer tu problema está en:

```
<%= if @article.errors.any? %>
```

debería ser

```
<% if @article.errors.any? %>
```